# Restricting Selenium/Webdriver/HtmlUnit to a certain domain

Tags: selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

While using selenium/webdriver for web scraping, I realized the target site has google analytics script running. Is there a way to restrict selenium/webdriver/htmlunit to avoid certain urls/domains ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think it is impossible becouse Selenium is actually adapter for several implementation. So he can't deny to load some scripts to firefox or chrome. Perhaps you can check driver api(firefox profile, htmlunit configuration file) to accomplish this.