# Whitelist domains Selenium / Firefox can connect to

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver with firefox. I am wondering if there is a setting i can change such that it to only requesting resources from certain domains. (Specifically i want it only to request content which is on the same domain as the webpage itself).

My current set up, written in Python, is:

```python
 from selenium import webdriver
 firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 ## Here, I change various default setting in Firefox, and install a couple of monitoring extensions
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
 driver.get(web_address)
```

What i want to do, is if i specify the web address `wwww.domain.com`, then to only load content served by `domain.com`, and not e.g. all the tracking content hosted by other domains that would typically be requested. Hoping could be achieved by a change to the profile settings in firefox, or via an extension.

Note - there is a similar question (without an answer) - [Restricting Selenium/Webdriver/HtmlUnit to a certain domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468624/restricting-selenium-webdriver-htmlunit-to-a-certain-domain) - but it is four years old, and i think Selenium has evolved a lot since then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/38168865/5409601

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With thanks to Vicky, (who's approach of using Proxy settings i followed - although directly from Selenium), the code below will change the proxy settings in firefox such that it will not connect to a domain except that on the white-list.

I suspect several setting changes are unnecessary and can be omitted for most purposes. Code in Python.

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    ## replace desired_domain.com below with whitelisted domain. Separate domains by comma.
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on","localhost,127.0.0.1,desired_domain.com")      

    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.ftp","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.ftp_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.socks","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.socks_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.ssl","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.backup.ssl_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl","0.0.0.0")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type",1)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings",True)       

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
    driver.get(web_address_desired)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is still impossible in selenium.But you can still achieve this by using proxies like browsermob. Webdriver integrates well with [browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) proxy.

**Sample pseudeocode in java**

```java
    //LittleProxy-powered 2.1.0 release

    LegacyProxyServer server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();

    server.start(0);

    // Blacklist websites
    server.blacklistRequests("https?://.*\\.blocksite\\.com/.*", 410);//these sites will be blocked

    /// get the Selenium proxy object
    Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(server);

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    // initialize the driver with the capabilities   ;
    Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction - my code, which works by changing firefox's poxy settings directly (i.e. without need for browsermob) is below